# Http to Https Redirecting not Working in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, https, aws-application-load-balancer

- I set up an EC2 Instance
- I uploaded an SSL Certificate and set it up correctly (Working)
- When i go to my site using https it loads properly therefore no error with the certificate
- I created an application Load Balancer
- I set everything up and set Redirecting in http to https port 443

This still doesn't redirect my http page requests
I tried the DNS Name (A Record) in in load balancer and it shows that the connection is not secure and then loads my website in http itself

Have i missed out any crucial part?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: how are you sending the traffic to the instance. are you sending the traffic from the load balancer to the instance via port 80 or 443. In your current setup the instance is configured with SSL certificate. Therefore you can send the traffic to the instance over port 443.

Comment: Why don't you upload the redirect setting screenshot?